# MySQL query for delete row if two columns are equal

Tags: php, mysql

How to delete all rows from a mysql table if values of two columns are equal

Example Table

```
invoice_id| item_id | name  | invoiced_qty | received_qty
---------------------------------------------------------
|  1      |  1      | item1 |   3          |     2    
|  2      |  2      | item2 |   5          |     5   
|  3      |  1      | item3 |   4          |     3   
|  4      |  2      | item4 |   2          |     2   
|  5      |  1      | item5 |   5          |     5
```

After deleting table needs to retains

```
invoice_id| item_id | name  | invoiced_qty | received_qty
---------------------------------------------------------
|  1      |  1      | item1 |   3          |     2    
|  3      |  1      | item3 |   4          |     3
```

The select query which i created is

```
SELECT * FROM table1 A 
INNER JOIN table1 B ON A.item_id = B.item_id 
AND A.invoice_id = B.invoice_id
AND A.invoiced_qty = B.received_qty
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/00c51/1/0):

```
DELETE FROM table1 
WHERE invoiced_qty = received_qty
```

Your edit does not change anything.  He is the [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4e4abe/2) demonstrating your SELECT query.  According to your sample data `A.invoice_id` will never equal `B.invoice_id`.  So you will not get any results.

Comment: was about to post that :P

Comment: i need to check the invoice_id and item_id also. same item_id, same invoice_id and equal qty

Comment: You are never going to have the same `invoice_id` in multiple records according to the sample data you provided.  It looks like your `invoice_id` is unique.  So there is no point in joining the table to itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply wrap your select statement and select values to be deleted by id, like this:

```
DELETE FROM table1 
WHERE item_id  IN (SELECT item_id FROM table1 A 
INNER JOIN table1 B ON A.item_id = B.item_id 
AND A.invoice_id = B.invoice_id
AND A.invoiced_qty = B.received_qty)
```

however you should accept answer by Linger as it is more straightforward solution, mine was to indicate that if you have something selected usually you can wrap and delete.

Comment: Sorry I forget to add one more column. There is a invoice_id also. I need to check both invoice_id and item_id.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
DELETE FROM table1 A
INNER JOIN table1 B ON A.item_id = B.item_id 
WHERE A.invoiced_qty = B.received_qty
```